# Let $N,K\unlhd G$ be finite with $(|N|,|K|)=1$. Prove that $ab=ba$ for every $a \in N$ ,$b \in K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $N,K\unlhd G$ where $N,K$ finite with $(|N|,|K|)=1$

I want to prove that $ab=ba$ for every $a \in N$ ,$b \in K$

The proof is not that hard but im struggling at the finish line.

I end up proving that $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \in N\cap K$

and since $(|N|,|K|)=1 \implies $ the only element in $N\cap K$ is $e$

but i have problems proving this one.

One way i tried was that for $g \in N\cap K$

and for $n$ the order of $N$

and for $m$ the order of $K$
from lagrange's theorem

$ord(g) / m $ and $ord(g) / n $

but for $m$ to be equal with $|K|$ i need K to be cyclic dont I?

Comment: No you don't need $K$ to be cyclic. If the order of $g$ divides both $m$ and $n$, then the order must be $1$, so $g=e$.

Comment: @DerekHolt i know that $(|N|,|K|)=1$ i dont know anything about $(m,n)$

Comment: ?????? In your post you defined $m$ to be the order of $K$ and $n$ to be the order of $N$.

Comment: As best I can guess, you're mixing up a group's **exponent** with its **order**.  If that is the case, even if $m$ were $K$'s exponent, Lagrange's theorem shows $m$ divides $|K|$, which is all we need.

Comment: @kostasNiths As a sanity check, please _define_ what you mean when you say "and for $m$ the order of $K$" without using the word "order".

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab= a^{-1}(b^{-1}ab) \in N$ and similarly $= (a^{-1}b^{-1}a)b \in K$.

Ok edit after remarks below: if $g \in N \cap K$, then $o(g) \mid |N|$, and $o(g) \mid |K|$ by Lagrange’s Theorem. Hence  $o(g) \mid (|N|,|K|)$.

Comment: Yes i know how to prove that but in order to prove that $ab=ba$ i need to prove that $a^{−1}b^{−1}ab=e$

Comment: Yes, but the poster said that they had proved that already and were having difficulties proving that $N \cap K = \{ e \}$ (althoguh as far as I can see they appear to have proved that too.)

Answer (score -1):

Suppose the intersection is not trivial, so that $N \cap K $ contains some non-identity element $g$.  The order of $g$ is at least 2, but must divide both $|N|$ and $|K|$.  However, this contradicts the fact that the only positive integer dividing both quantities is 1 (they are relatively prime).  Hence $N \cap K$ cannot contain non-trivial elements.  Note that since for any subgroups $N \cap K$ is also a subgroup, it must be non-empty, hence it contains only the identity.

Answer (score -1):

$N\cap K$ is a subgroup of both $N$ and $K$. By Lagrange’s theorem, $\lvert N \cap K\rvert$ divides both $\lvert N \rvert$ and $\lvert K \rvert$. But the greatest common divisor of $\lvert N \rvert$ and $\lvert K \rvert$ is $1$, which means $N\cap K$ is the trivial group.